# Can CMake tell me which Module or Config file is used for find_package()?

Tags: cmake

I sometimes find myself wondering which `Find<package>.cmake` file CMake is actually using.
For instance I have two `FindOpenMP.cmake` files on my system, and I would like to know which one is used – if any – with

```
find_package(OpenMP)
```

**Can CMake print the location of the module file used to resolve a `find_package()` call?**

I am using CMake 3.18.2.

Comment: Take a look at the search procedure on `find_package()`: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#search-procedure
CMake searches that paths in given order. So whichever hit the search, uses that one.

Comment: Have you tried `--debug-find` and `--trace-source=<file>` options?

Comment: `--debug-find` looks very useful for this, basically the answer I'd say.

Comment: Interestingly, `--debug-find` or setting `set(CMAKE_FIND_DEBUG_MODE TRUE)` does not show anything for openmp on Ubuntu 16.04 with cmake 3.15.2, while it does for all other `find_package()`s. Weird.

Answer (score 4):

### Config mode

If CMake uses **config** script (`FooConfig.cmake` or `config-foo.cmake`) for process `find_package(Foo)` request, then it sets:

1. `Foo_DIR` **cache** variable pointed to the *directory* with the script.
   You may check this variable outside of the project, in the `CMakeCache.txt` file created in the build directory.
2. `Foo_CONFIG` variable contained absolute path to the script.
   You may print content of this variable in the `CMakeLists.txt` after the `find_package()` call.

### Module mode

If CMake uses **module** script (`FindFoo.cmake`) for process `find_package(Foo)` request, then it sets none variable pointed to the script.

But search procedure for such script is quite simple:

1. CMake firstly checks a directory with modules, **shipped** with CMake itself.
2. CMake iterates **in order** over directories listed in `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` CMake variable, and stops after finding the first file with the expected name (`FindFoo.cmake`).

That is, you may print the value of `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` variable, and manually (or by some other scripting) iterate over this value and find the first directory which contains required script.